# Excel Code merging a IF and Countif function

Tags: excel

I've just got a simple question to ask about some excel coding

I've got a table of data as such;

```
a   1
a   0
a   1
a   1
b   1
b   1
b   0
c   1
c   1
c   1
```

I'm trying to write a code on excel that counts the number of ones for the different letter; I tried it with a code

```
=IF(A3:A8 = "a", COUNTIF(B3:B8,"1"), "")
```

but it comes up as `#VALUE` when I enter it in.

Any help would be appreciated

Kind Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can use `COUNTIFS` for this: `=COUNTIFS(A3:A8,"a",B3:B8,1)`.